# Planar curve whose radius vector is parallel to its acceleration vector is either a line or a circle

Tags: differential-geometry, plane-curves

We are considering a $C^2$ curve $c: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^2$ that is parametrized by arc-length (so unit speed) and satisfies det$\begin{pmatrix}c_1& c_2&\\
c_1''& c_2''
\end{pmatrix} = 0$. I would like to show that $c$ is either a line or a circle centered at the origin.

If we can reduce to the cases that $c''$ is either identically zero or non-zero everywhere, then we are done. Is it possible to reduce to these cases from the given assumptions? Otherwise we just have that $c$ is constructed piece-wise by lines and circular arcs.

Comment: The constraint implies $$c_1c_2'' = c_2c_1'' \iff \frac{c_1''}{c_1} = \frac{c_2''}{c_2}$$ which is trivially true for any linear $c_1,c_2$

Answer (score 1):

From the determinant condition we have the proportion $c_1:c_1''=c_2:c_2''$. If $c_1=0$ or $c_2=0$ we get the coordinate axes, which are lines. If neither is $0$ and $c_1''=0$ then $c_2''=0$ for the proportion to hold, and integrating twice we get general lines.

Now consider the case when nothing in the proportion is $0$. From the natural parametrization condition we have that $c_1'^2+c_2'^2=1$, and differentiating $c_1'c_1''+c_2'c_2'' = 0$. The proportion then implies $c_1'c_1+c_2'c_2 = 0$ (replacing values by proportional ones), and integrating $c_1^2+c_2^2=\text{const}$. But this is the equation of a circle centered at the origin.

The converse, that naturally parameterized lines and circles satisfy the determinant condition, is easy to check by direct differentiation.

Comment: Starting with a circle centered at the origin and a line tangent to this circle, how do I know that my curve doesn't travel along the tangent line and then jump to the circle at the point of tangency?

Comment: @LCrouch Such a thing will not be twice differentiable at the point of tangency. The curve has to be at least twice differentiable for the determinant condition to make sense.

Comment: We can actually assume that the curve is C^2. It isn't obvious to me that such a thing will not be twice differentiable (probably just have to think about it some more), but I guess the second derivative would have to jump at the point of tangency.

Comment: @LCrouch The proof in the post goes through for $C^2$, so no such patchwork curves, or any others, satisfy the two conditions. But it is also easy to see directly: the second derivative of a line is $0$ and of a circle is not, there will indeed be a jump. Moving from line to another line will have a jump already in the first derivative.